# Test w/ Capybara/Rspec/Rails4 a link_to with dynamic id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec-rails

I was wondering what would be the best way to test a click on a `link_to` inside of an iterated table with dynamic id?

```
scenario 'select customer from the list' do
  sign_in_with user
  visit customers_path
  ## and here I would like to fire this action
end
```

And my table would be populated as such

```
%table.table.table-striped
  %thead
    %tr
      %th
        Name
      %th

  %tbody
    - @customers.each do |customer|
      %tr
        %td
          = customer.name
        %td
          = link_to '', root_path, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-usd pull-right', id: "customer_#{customer.id}"
          = link_to '', customer, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in pull-right', id: "customer_#{customer.id}"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Capybara will match the id the same as the text...

```
    @customer = Customer.all.sample
    click_link "customer_%d"%@customer.id
```